# slow DOM updates with CSS3 in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, dom

When adding lot of elements to the DOM in IE9+, the existence of CSS3 rules seem to slow down the reflow, even though they're unused.

jsfiddle demonstrating the issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/2wfAq/19/

```
var name = "long_id_is_long_so_very_long";
var selectHtml = '<select id="' + name + '" name="data[long][id][is][long][so][very][long]">';

var start = Date.now();
var docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();
var options = [];
var counter = 0;
$.each(optionsList, function (index, option) {
    options.push('<option id="' + name + '_' + counter+++'" value="' + option.value + '">' + option.content + '</option>');
});

var newContainer = document.createElement('span');
newContainer.innerHTML = selectHtml + options.join('\n') + "</select>";
docFrag.appendChild(newContainer);

var oldContainer = $('#' + name);
var domStart = Date.now();
oldContainer.after(docFrag);
console.log("[" + name + "] dom insertion: " + (Date.now() - domStart));
oldContainer.remove();

console.log("[" + name + "] complete render: " + (Date.now() - start));
```

This is only an issue in IE9-11, it reflows fine in IE7-8 (presumably due to no CSS3 support), as well as Chrome and Firefox.

Is there any way to get these elements into the page faster?
The CSS3 rules are part of a common stylesheet and I can not remove them

I attempted deleting the rules via javascript too, but that did not seem to have any affect either. (http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Totally_Pwn_CSS_with_Javascript)